# Indexnumber from an multipleArray

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have some fields:

```
dummy[1]
dummy[2]
dummy[3]
```

We catch the changed input via `on.('change')` and became the object, how can we extract the current arraynumber?

Example: when i got `dummy[2]` .. how can i get the "2" as count from the input field into a new var todo something with?

we tried some things but nothing works out, can it only solved via regex catching?

Comment: `on("change", function(event) { // here, "this" may reference to the selected dummy, else you change search into event param });`

Comment: yes then i have the name attr -> dummy[2], how to extract the index? 2 for this example

Comment: Let's say name attribute is stored in `name` var : `var reg = name.match(/\[(\d)\]$/i);` Then you will get your number in reg[1]

Answer (score 1):

great! solved it with the regex, thanks alot :-)

```
$arrayMatchCount = $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('name').match(/[(\‌​d)]$/i);

if ($arrayMatchCount !== null && $arrayMatchCount.length > 1) {
    $arrayCount = $arrayMatchCount[1];
    ...
}
```